# android automatically download bad apps

Tags: security, malware

as you can see in the following picture

[image]

there are apps such as "Solitaire", "Ball Sort", "Count Masters", "Galaxy Attack" and many others that keep automatically downloaded on my android phone after that I remove them.

I already managed to install software such as

Avast Mobile Security
Avira Securty

But they do not block those apps from being automatically downloaded.

Further more, I have a kind of newspaper that constantly reports me fake news about cars, such as Fiat has failed, Schumacher is death and so on.

I am stock of all of this and I would like you to help me fixing this issue.

Comment: remove all samsung/google accounts and factory reset phone

Comment: Could you mention the device model and Android version? I'd assume this is a Xiaomi device since there's a similar report on Reddit: [Strange apps appearing on my phone](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/fvw8eo/strange_apps_appearing_on_my_phone/). If that's the case, then perhaps this might help: [How to remove ads in Xiaomi phones with MIUI](https://www.androidauthority.com/remove-ads-xiaomi-miui-1019139/).

Comment: Xiaomi, Redmi Note 9 Pro with a Android 11 installed on it

Comment: So yes, read and understand the previous comment and included links. Nothing else to add.